# Why won't this variable reference to a non-local scope resolve?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, spyder, global-scope

Here's an example to find the greatest common divisor for positive integers `a` and `b`, and `a <= b`. I started from the smaller `a` and minus one by one to check if it's the divisor of both numbers.

```
def gcdFinder(a, b):

    testerNum = a   

    def tester(a, b):
        if b % testerNum == 0 and a % testerNum == 0:
            return testerNum
        else:
            testerNum -= 1
            tester(a, b)

    return tester(a, b)

print(gcdFinder(9, 15))
```

Then, I got error message,

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'testerNum' referenced before assignment`.

After using `global testerNum`, it successfully showed the answer `3` in Spyder console...

[image: spyder's outcome]

but in pythontutor.com, it said `NameError: name 'testerNum' is not defined` ([link](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=def%20gcdFinder%28a,%20b%29%3A%0A%0A%20%20%20%20testerNum%20%3D%20a%20%20%20%0A%0A%20%20%20%20def%20tester%28a,%20b%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20global%20testerNum%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20b%20%25%20testerNum%20%3D%3D%200%20and%20a%20%25%20testerNum%20%3D%3D%200%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20testerNum%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20testerNum%20-%3D%201%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20tester%28a,%20b%29%0A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20tester%28a,%20b%29%0A%0Aprint%28gcdFinder%289,%2015%29%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=8&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)).

[image: pythontutor's outcome]

<s>**Q1:** In Spyder, I think that the `global testerNum` is a problem since `testerNum = a` is not in global scope. It's inside the scope of function `gcdFinder`. Is this description correct? If so, how did Spyder show the answer?</s>

**Q2:** In pythontutor, say the last screenshot, how to solve the NameError problem in pythontutor?

<s>**Q3:** Why there's difference between the results of Spyder and pythontutor, and which is correct?</s>

**Q4:** Is it better not to use `global` method?

--

UPDATE: The Spyder issue was due to the value stored from previous run, so it's defined as `9` already. And this made the `global testerNum` work. I've deleted the Q1 & Q3.

Comment: not answer to any of your questions, I think it would be better to parse the testerNum as parametr so function `tester` would be defined: `def tester(a, b, testerNum)`

Comment: actually it is answer to your questions 2 and 4 :D

Comment: In the sample code `testNum` is not `global`. Try using the key word `nonlocal` instead. This assumes that you are using python3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The Problem:**

When trying to resolve a variable reference, Python first checks in the local scope and then in the local scope of any enclosing functions. For example this code:

```
def foo():
    x=23
    def bar():
        return x +1
    return bar

print(foo()())
```

Will run and print out `24` because when `x` is referenced inside of `bar`, since there is no `x` in the local scope it finds it in the scope of the enclosing function (`foo`). However, as soon as you try to assign to a variable, Python assumes it is defined in the local scope. So this:

```
def foo():
    x=23
    def bar():
        x = x + 1
        return x
    return bar

print(foo()())
```

Will throw an `UnboundLocalError` because I am trying to assign to `x` which means it is going to be looked up in the local scope, but the value I'm trying to assign to it is based on the `x` from the enclosing scope. Since the assignment limits the search for `x` to the local scope, it can't be found and I get the error.

So your error is coming up because of the `testerNum -= 1` line in your else clause, it is limiting the search for `testerNum` to the local scope where it doesn't exist.

**The Fix:**

The `global` declaration isn't right since, as you noted, `testerNum` isn't defined in the global scope. I'm not familiar with Spyder and don't know why it worked there but it seems like it somehow got a `testerNum` variable in its global scope.

If you're using Python3 you can get around this by changing your `global testerNum` line to `nonlocal testerNum` which just tells Python that, despite being assigned to, testerNum isn't defined in the local scope and to keep searching outwards.

```
def foo():
    x=23
    def bar():
        nonlocal x
        x = x + 1
        return x
    return bar

>>> print(foo()())
24
```

Another option that would work in Python 2 or 3 is to pass around `testerNum` as Brambor outlined in their answer.

Comment: Thanks, pretty clear explanation, especially the 3rd paragraph.

Comment: So I can say, it's okay to call a variable outside the function, but if I want to make change of it, that's not gonna work.

Comment: @chenghuayang Correct, unless you can declare it `nonlocal`.

Comment: Is `nonlocal` not recommended either? It asks computer to search outside and this consume somewhat processing.

Comment: @chenghuayang It isn't going to consume any amount of processing power you'll ever notice. As to whether it is bad form, that is certainly going to be a matter of opinion. I think in some cases is can be useful but it can definitely cause some confusion and it is probably safer to avoid as a general practice

Answer (score 2):

Answers to **Q2** and **Q4**.

As I wrote in the comments, you can parse the testerNum as parameter.

Your code would then look like this:

```
def gcdFinder(a, b):

    testerNum = a   

    def tester(a, b, testerNum):
        if b % testerNum == 0 and a % testerNum == 0:
            return testerNum
        else:
            testerNum -= 1
            return tester(a, b, testerNum)  # you have to return this in order for the code to work

    return tester(a, b, testerNum)

print(gcdFinder(9, 15))
```

edit: (see coment)

Comment: This solved the problem. Thanks. But is it weird if I set a variable outside the function and also set it as a parameter within the function?

Comment: I'm not exaxtly sure what do you mean. If your concern is regarding code `a = 5; def double(x): return x*2; print(double(a))`. If it is overlaping `x` and `a` in your code, then no, it is not wierd

Comment: OK, got it. Just better to use different word.

Answer (score 0):

TO hit only question 4, yes, it's better not to use `global` at all.  `global` generally highlights poor code design.

You're going to a lot of trouble; I strongly recommend that you look up standard methods of calculating the GCD, and implement Euclid's Algorithm instead.  Coding details left as an exercise for the student.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and info. [Euclid's Algorithm](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/the-euclidean-algorithm) is really a good way to calculate GCD.